# Set height of div wrapper by image width size

Tags: javascript, jquery

Going to try and re-explain what I am trying to do here. It seems there is a little confusion around the `div` / `img` example. In short, what I am trying to do is create a wrapper around an image that stays as a square, but expands in size responsively as the browser window adjusts. The image inside the square will also adjust size within the square wrapper (`div`) to fill the space. The images are all pretty much the same width, but the height varies, and I want to position on top and hide the bottom for anything larger then the square wrapper. Because the square wrapper will resize with the window I cannot set a size an actual size to this `div`, but would like to adjust automatically.

Hope this helps.

So here is what I came up with. Which seems to work for the most part.

```
var divWidth = $('.photo').width();
$('.photo').height(divWidth);

$(window).resize(function () {
    var divWidth = $('.photo').width();
    $('.photo').height(divWidth);
});
```

Anyone have any suggestions to add?

--- original description ----

I'm looking to create a responsive web page with images. Unfortunately not all the images have the same height to width ratio. So was thinking of creating a wrapper around the image that would set the height by the current width of the image, and the rest would be hidden. Looking for the best and simplest way to do this?

So what this does is it creates a 2 column list of items that expand with the width of the browser. But unfortunate because of the image sizes some of the items are taller then others. And I want the image to be in a square box width equal widths for conformity. But I don't want to resize the images height wise, just fill 100% width wise, and overflow on the bottom.

CSS:

```
.listing ul {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.listPeople li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 48.93617020799999%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #D0D5D8;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

    .listPeople li .user .photo {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        background: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 0;
    }

.listing li .user .photo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.listing li .content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 74.468085099%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="listing">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="user">
                <div class="photo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="URL" /></a>
                </div>
                <a class="button">Follow</a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                -- normal html formatting --
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The code, where is it? (Show us what you've tried and what you're struggling with)

Answer (score 1):

I would set the width of the container and then just use the attribute `style="max-width:100%"` on the `img` tag.

```
<p><img src="http://whiterootmedia.com/images/css_rule.jpg" alt="css rule" style="max-width:100%" /></p>
```

Here is an example: http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/what_are_css_selectors.html

Comment: I think if youre ok with defining all the widths to be the same then this is the best idea. And it doesnt use js so thats a nicer solution.

If you want to make the images sit in a box that has its width and height equal to the width of the image, then this wont do that.

Comment: Trying not to hand code the width/height's so they can expand dynamically when the browser is resized.

Comment: That's what's great about this solution. Set your container to whatever you want (i.e. pixels, em, %, etc.) and the picture will scale to fit inside it. No cropping or picture dimensions necessary. If you look at my link (http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/what_are_css_selectors.html) the whole page is responsive.

Comment: In my example above the <li> actually expands by the width of the browser window. So the div ".user" also expands in per portion of the <li> hence the div with the image ".photo" also expands. I'm looking for a way to keep the -- in this case -- photos the same square shape, but the photos used have different heights. So looking for a way to constrain the height ratio of ".photo" to the width of the wrapping container ".user".

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the **img** in a **div**.
2. Set the **div** [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y) style property to `hidden`.
3. Set the image **width** to your liking.
4. Set the **div** width to image width.

---

**Update**

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img') /* get all image elements */,
    i,
    div;

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    // set the div overflow-y style property to hidden
    div.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    // wrap the image in the div
    div.appendChild(imgs[i]);
    imgs[i].parentElement.replaceChild(div, imgs[i]);
    // set the image width to your liking
    imgs[i].style.width = YOUR_WIDTH + 'px'; // replace YOUR_WIDTH with whatever you want
    // set the div width to image width
    div.style.width = imgs[i].style.width;
}
```

**Note 1**: I didn't test it but it should work

**Note 2**: **Div**s are displayed as **block**s by default, consider using **span**s or set the divs `display` style to `inline` if you want them to be displayed inline.

Comment: I'm trying to do this dynamically and don't want to set a static width/height

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? You can set the width and style with javascript.

Comment: Can you recommend any scripts or plugins?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/keep-aspect-ratio-with-html-and-css) explains how keep a div always squared, only using HTML and CSS. But it uses some `position:absolute` to achieve that. But it's just a matter of adding a wrapper with `position:relative;` so it's top/bottom/left/right will respect the wrapper's rather than using window's position.

For the image to be cropped when it's bigger than square, just add `overflow:hidden;` on the square div, while adding `max-width:100%;` on the image so it will always preserve it's own aspect-ratio while never getting cropped (in width).